# Retrieve AWS ssm parameter in bulk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ssm

How can I retrieve parameters from AWS Systems Manager (parameter store) in bulk (or more than one parameter) at a time? Using aws-sdk, following is the Node.js code I have written to retrieve SSM parameter from parameter store:

```
      const ssm = new (require('aws-sdk/clients/ssm'))()

      const getSSMKey = async params => {
          const {Parameter: {Value: APIKey}} = await ssm.getParameter(params).promise()
          return APIKey
    }

    const [param1, param2, param3] = await Promise.all([
      getSSMKey({ Name: '/data/param/PARAM1', WithDecryption: true }),
      getSSMKey({ Name: '/data/param/PARAM2', WithDecryption: true }),
      getSSMKey({ Name: '/data/param/PARAM3', WithDecryption: true })
    ])
    console.log(param1, param2, param3)
```

But with this code, I am sending 3 request for getting 3 parameters which is inefficient in case of large number of parameters. Is there any way to retrieve more than one parameters in one request. if ssm.getParameters() is the method to do that then please give an example (particularly parameter to that method). I tried but I receive nothing.

Answer (score 15):

According to the [AWS document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SSM.html#getParameter-property), `GetParameter` gets the value for one parameter, whereas `GetParameters` gets the value for multiple.

Their usages are very similar too. When using `GetParameters` to get multiple values, pass in multiple names as a list for `Names`, instead of passing a single name as string for `Name`.

Code sample, to get parameters named "foo" and "bar", in "us-west-1" region:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ region: "us-west-1" });

const SSM = require('aws-sdk/clients/ssm');
const ssm = new SSM()
const query = {
    "Names": ["foo", "bar"],
    "WithDecryption": true
}
let param = ssm.getParameters(query, (err, data) => {
    console.log('error = %o', err);
    console.log('raw data = %o', data);
})
```

Answer (score 9):

At last it worked for me. Following is the code:

```
        const ssmConfig = async () => {
          const data = await ssm.getParameters({ Names: ['/data/param/PARAM1', '/data/param/PARAM2', '/bronto/rest//data/param/PARAM3'],
WithDecryption: true }).promise()
          const config = {}
          for (const i of data.Parameters) {
            if (i.Name === '/data/param/PARAM1') {
              config.param1 = i.Value
            }
            if (i.Name === '/data/param/PARAM2') {
              config.rest.clientId param2 = i.Value
            }
            if (i.Name === '/data/param/PARAM3') {
              config.param3 = i.Value
            }
          }
          return config
        }
```

Comment: just so if anyone is wondering, you can throw this in a try/catch block as well, but you must have the .promise at the end of the get parameters statement

Comment: It's worth noting that the order of parameters in the result is not the same as the order in the input. Looping over the results, or something like that, is required as shown. If it's just a few parameters you may want to user `GetParameter` with `const [parm1, parm2, etc] = Promise.all([...])` to simplify your code a bit.

Comment: @GaryMcM I wish the Client SDK API docs would make this explicitly clear because as someone new to AWS I've been caught out by making this assumption based on the returned parameters coincidentally happening to be in the same order of the requested parameters....until the day they didn't. ‍♂️

Comment: I just ran into this same order issue. I submitted feedback on their documentation page to call this out explicitly, because it makes no mention of the order of the results.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I did to retrieve all the parameters from a specific path.

```
**your SSM function  client :**
'use strict';
const SSM = require('aws-sdk/clients/ssm');
let ssmclient;
module.exports.init = () => {
    const region = process.env.REGION === undefined ? 'us-east-1' : process.env.REGION ;
    ssmclient = new SSM({region: region});
}
module.exports.getParameters = async (path) => {
    try {
        let params = {
            Path: path,
            WithDecryption: true
        };
        let allParameters = [];
        let data =  await ssmclient.getParametersByPath(params).promise();
        allParameters.push.apply(allParameters, data.Parameters);
        while(data.NextToken) {
            params.NextToken = data.NextToken;
            data =  await ssmclient.getParametersByPath(params).promise();
            allParameters.push.apply(allParameters, data.Parameters);
        }
        return allParameters;
    } catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
}
calling this client:

const ssm = require("yourssmclinet");
ssm.init();
// you call only once to retrieve everything which falls under /data/param
const parameters = await getParameters("/data/param");
//from here you can fetch parameters['what ever needed'].
```

Answer (score 1):

You essentially have two options to get parameters in bulk.

One is the method provided by @user1032613, but the other is to use the built-in function getParametersByPath().

A Lambda code example in node with all three methods can be seen below. Each method can take different params, for instance with the path you can make filters, etc. to get the exact values you need, see [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SSM.html#getParametersByPath-property).

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const SSM = new AWS.SSM();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    //Example get single item
    const singleParam = { Name: 'myParam' };
    const getSingleParam = await SSM.getParameter(singleParam).promise();

    //Example: Get Multiple values
    const multiParams = {
        Names: [ 'myParam1', 'myParam2', 'myParam3' ],
        WithDecryption: true
    };

    const getMultiParams = await SSM(multiParams).promise();

    //Example: Get all values in a path
    const pathParams = { Path: '/myPath/', WithDecryption: true };
    const getPathParams = await SSM.getParametersByPath(pathParams).promise();

    return 'Success';
};
```

Remember that you can also use environment variables. For example, you could write singleParam like this:

```
const singleParam = { Name: process.env.PARAM }
```

That way you can have code that extracts code from DEV, PROD, etc. depending on the stage.